# Can I temporarily put a 2.5" HDD into a 3.5" USB enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My laptop is crashing and I suspect my HDD, can I test it in a 3.5" USB enclosure (assuming it fits), or is that a bad idea.
I don't have a desktop PC, and the BSOD logs fail to save, so if you have another suggestion how to determine whether the HDD is the cause, that would do as well.

Comment: Depending on the manufacturer of your laptop, there should be a hdd test accessible through startup menu. For example HP has a menu diagnostic tools when F9 is pressed on startup. Look for the options at startup of your computer. That way, you don't need to do any physical work to test the HDD.

Comment: It's an HP laptop and I run the extensive HDD test. All but the long test passed. Here is the error log: Long DST Completed - Result 3 Error Code=0x305      I just want to verify it's not a faulty connection or motherboard.

Comment: As soon as we get an error code on an integrated test like that, it's best to replace the drive. Chance of it being wiring is very slim. But as already answered, for short tests like this, it won't harm. In worst case, you could use some tape to hold it in place in a bigger case. Know that there are brackets to hold 2,5" drives in 3,5" provided spaces.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I temporarily put a 2½ HDD into a 3½ USB enclosure?

Assuming it is SAS or SATA: Yes you can (and it will work).
You probabably cannot screw it into place, but for emergency recoveries this is no problem.

If you have an old IDE/PATA disk then it is also possible but will need an additional convertor. (The 2½ inch PATA connectors are smaller and include the lines for power.).

> If you have another suggestion how to determine whether the HDD is 
>   the cause, that would do as well.

1. Anything logged in the event viewer? (start run eventvwr.msc).
2. If installed, local diagnistics (Good one Terry).
3. Else any SMART capable tool to check disk statistics.

Comment: As far as I can tell SMART seems to be fine. The only possibly useful info in event viewer is this: "Agent proxy DNS unable to allocate 0 bytes of memory. This may mean that the system is low on virtual memory or the memory manager encountered an internal error." (its a translation) Around the time of a couple of crashes. I see a lot of SharedAccess_NAT errors in history though.

Comment: What happens if you boot from a live CD. Is the system stable and fast or also slow?